# sql query, return all persons that are more than 5 years older than everybody they know

Tags: mysql, database

I have these 2 tables:
Persons(id, name, address, age)
Knows (id, personA_id --> Persons, personB_id-->Persons) and I want to return all persons that are more than 5 years older than everybody they know.  I have tried this:

```
SELECT distinct P1.name
FROM Persons P1 
INNER JOIN Knows K ON K.personA_id = P1.id
INNER JOIN Persons P2 ON K.personB_id = P2.id 
GROUP BY P1.name
HAVING MIN(P1.age - P2.age) > 5
```

but I don't seem to find out what went wrong

I got
Woody allen

expected
Woody allen
Susan Sarandon
[what went wrong?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Mow.png)

Comment: Use WHERE NOT EXISTS.

Comment: DISTINCT makes no sense - P1.name is already unique.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Persons p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM Knows k
                   JOIN Persons p2
                   WHERE k.personA_id = p1.id
                     AND k.personB_id = p2.id
                     AND p2.age > p1.age - 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT p1.name
FROM Persons p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
FROM Knows k
JOIN Persons p2
WHERE k.personA_id = p1.id
AND k.personB_id = p2.id
AND p2.age > p1.age - 6 );